# Rendering array of nested react components not working

Tags: reactjs

This is the link to my code - [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/q8y99lqw2j)

What I want is to see is array of charts (Line Chart and Bar Chart) should come one below another. But it only shows Bar Chart and Line Chart doesn't render at all, also button icons doesn't show up either.
But when I comment out 714-765 lines of code, basically hiding the condition to check and render Bar Chart, I see Line Chart appears and button icons also show up. I have pulled out all my hairs but cannot understand why it is happening? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: **Too much code.** You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need to **isolate the problem** and debug from there. If you're stuck, provide a **clear explanation of what isn't working** with a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading **[ask]** a good question and **[the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)**. Also, be sure to take the **[tour]** and read **[this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/im-new-to-stack-overflow-what-are-some-things-i-should-do-and-what-things-wil)**.

Comment: you also need to have keys when you are mapping over an array in react.